# How to run Python method only once, durning the program life cycle?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have built a Python Flask REST API, which reacts to POST requests. Every time the endpoint is called, file from server is read. I was wondering is there any way for the file to be read in only once?

I would like to have it so that reading from file is done only once the program is launched. At the moment file is read in every time the "/test" endpoint is called.

This is an example of the controller:

```py
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test(data):
    file_content = Data.readFile()
    ...
    "Here do something with the file content and data"
```

Here is the content of Data.py:

```py
def readFile():
    with open(os.getcwd() + '/csv_files/' + config.WORDS, encoding="utf-8-sig", mode='r') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        file_content = [row[0] for row in csv_reader]
    return file_content
```

I know that in Java Spring you can use @PostConstruct or @Configuration. Is there something similar in Python?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you can just move the call to `readFile` from the route to the "global" space, ie under the definition of `app`

Comment: This is similar to [memoization](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php) but you could probably do something more simple like having a global variable.

Comment: It depends. Does it change every now and then? If so, then you can use Redis with a timeout by caching a method which returns the content of the file. https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#caching-other-functions . Note: this might be slower than user a global variable, however this allows for adding a timeout and overall it just looks cleaner.

Comment: are you looking Singleton pattern implementation in python

Comment: Have you checked out [Sessions](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/quickstart/#sessions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a closure function for this.

```py
# Data.py
def read_file():
    # the variable `read_file` is being modified inside the function
    # ignoring the global declaration will create a local variable read_file
    global read_file

    with open(os.getcwd() + '/csv_files/' + config.WORDS, encoding="utf-8-sig", mode='r') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        file_content = [row[0] for row in csv_reader]

    def inner():
        return file_content

    # read file is a global variable 
    # because it is declared as a function in the global scope
    # we are modifying it here and monkey patching it with `inner`
    # subsequent calls to `read_file` will inherently call `inner`
    read_file = inner

    # for the first time the function is called
    return file_content
```

The first time you call `read_file()`, the file is opened and `file_content` is loaded into the variable and the variable `read_file` gets replaced by the `inner` function.
For subsequent method calls, the value of `file_content` is simply returned by the `inner` function.

Answer (score 1):

Change the controller so the file data is already read outside of the function.

```
pre_file_content = Data.readFile()
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test(data):
    file_content = pre_file_content
    ...
    "Here do something with the file content and data"
```